# If column exist input one value else put in another

Tags: sql, if-statement

I am attempting to make a master table based on smaller tables that I received. The smaller tables have some duplicates and some unique columns.The smaller tables I also receive in batches meaning the columns in the master table need to be updated. I am trying to check if a columns exists then input a value as 2013_x else cast(0 as float) as [2013_x]

```
......
into
   output.Master_Table   
from
    (select
        a.[Name_Columns] 
        , case when exists(SELECT 1 FROM Sys.columns c 
        where c.[object_id]= OBJECT_ID('output.Activity') and c.name = a.[1010]) then 1 else 0 end [2013_1010]
......
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Understand that you are attempting and trying to do certain things...but what can't you do? Please provide the full sql statement you have tried so far.

Comment: How do I perform this statement? if a columns exists then input a value as 2013_x else cast(0 as float) as [2013_x]

Answer (score 0):

From the given note I have understand that,

- You have some list of tables
- You are trying to create master table which have all columns from those list.

If my understanding is correct then use the following query..

**This will get you all the columns from the list of tables**

```
-- Use this if your tables have some common name
select DISTINCT name,OBJECT_ID  into #tbl
  from sys.all_columns 
 where OBJECT_ID in (select ID from dbo.sysobjects  where name like '%Partial Table Name%' )

-- OR

-- If you want to specify the list use this  

select DISTINCT name,OBJECT_ID  into #tbl
  from sys.all_columns 
 where OBJECT_ID in (object_id('TableName'), object_id('TableName'),object_id('TableName'))
```

**Following will give you the column name with its data type. you can just copy paste the result & execute it. Now you are available with the master table with all columns**

```
select 'create table MASTERTABLE  ('
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct
    c.name +' ' + 
    t.Name + ' (' +
    convert(varchar(100),c.max_length )+'),'
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
join #tbl dd on
    c.object_id = dd.object_id 
    and c.name = dd.name
where t.Name like '%varchar%'

union all

SELECT distinct
    c.name +' ' + 
    t.Name  +','
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
join #tbl dd on
    c.object_id = dd.object_id 
    and c.name = dd.name
where t.Name not like '%varchar%'
UNION ALL
SELECT ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this in the wrong way. You shouldn't be 'unsure' of your schema in the sense that you'll use a column "if it exists". This typically leads to overly complex, slow and fragile systems.

You also generally want to avoid data duplication. But I'll answer that anyway especially since the technique can serve other purposes such as moving data from staging tables into a master table.
I'll also show an example of how you can avoid the duplication.

For the purposes of this answer let's assume you have the following tables:

```
MasterTable(ID, COL1, COL3, COL6)
SmallTable1(ID, COL1, COL2, COL3)
SmallTable2(ID, COL1, COL4, COL5, COL6)
```

To add data from each of the small tables to MasterTable, use the following queries:

```
INSERT  MasterTable (ID, COL1, COL3)
SELECT  ID, COL1, COL3
FROM    SmallTable1
```

You can even set defaults values for columns not in the SmallTable, or perform calculations from multiple SmallTable columns into a single MasterTable column:

```
INSERT  MasterTable(ID, COL1, COL3, COL6)
SELECT  ID, COL1, 'Default', COL5 + COL6
FROM    SmallTable2
```

---

**Alternative**: avoiding duplication. Generally you want to avoid duplicating data that has the same meaning in different places, because this can easily lead to inconsistencies if the values are not kept in synch. You'll often hear *excuses* "justifying" why the duplication is required. But it's important to be aware how you can easily combine data from multiple tables.

This example uses slightly different sample tables:

```
MasterTable(ID, COL1)
SmallTable1(ID, COL2, COL3)
SmallTable2(ID, COL4, COL5, COL6)
```

And the following query combines all 3 tables into a single result-set on the fly.

```
SELECT  m.ID, m.COL1, s1.COL2, s1.COL3, s2.COL4, s2.COL5 + s2.COL6 AS CalculatedColumn
FROM    MasterTable m
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SmallTable1 s1 ON
            s1.ID = m.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SmallTable2 s2 ON
            s2.ID = m.ID
```